# In which scenario should a Citrix Administrator configure additional NetScaler session policies in an existing environment?

Tags: citrix, xenapp, xendesktop

These the the options:

A. Users need VPN access.
B. User devices need to be scanned.
C. Multiple **[XenDesktop](http://www.ssdntech.com/Citrix-XenDesktop-certification-Training.aspx)** sites are in use in the environment.
D. Multiple authentication methods are used in the environment.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It would be more appropriate to ask this on serverfault.com or the Citrix forums.

Answer (score 0):

Answer should be B because without scanning user devices configuration policies can't be recognized.